# How to pre-populate Django form with part of URL?

Tags: python, django

I'm completely new to programming (Django), and I'm trying to pre-populate a django_messages form with a snippet of the URL.

For example, for a compose form at **www.mywebsite.com/compose_root/Chris88**, I want the "Recipient" field to be pre-populated with "Chris88".

**Is there any way to do this?  In urls.py, I have:**

```
url(r'^compose_root/(<recipient>[\w.@+-]+)/$', compose, name='messages_compose_to'),
```

I already tried plugging in recipient as an initial in the "Recipient" form field, but it didn't work, so it might be easier just to pre-populate with an excerpt of the URL.

Help is much appreciated.

Comment: Can you post the code you were using to put recipient as initial data in the form?  It should work if you use something like `form = MyForm(initial={'Recipient':recipient})`

Comment: It gives me the NameError: name 'recipient' not defined, even though I have "recipient" in the Message model (which is imported).

Comment: what does the `compose` view look like?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a form that looks something like:

```
class New_form(Form.form):
    ... FormStuff
    recipient = Some Field
```

Add a view that looks like:

```
def compose_root(request,recipient):
     ...# View Stuff
     form = New_form(initial={"recipient": recipient})
     return render_to_response('form-template.html', {'form':form})
```

And in your form-template

```
{{form}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a `DjangoMessages` Form class, you can modify the `get_form(self)` method. Get the form field and set its `initial` value to the url parameter `recipient`

```py
class DjangoMessages(Form):

    def get_form(self):
        form = super().get_form()
        form.fields['recipient'].initial = self.kwargs['recipient']
```